# Issue with .dropna() in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In the below function I am working with a Pandas dataframe.  I am bringing in a data frame, and immediately resetting the index.  I then make a copy of that dataframe so I avoid any Chained Assignment issues.

I then want to use `.dropna(inplace=True, subset = [header], axis=0)` to remove any rows where my column of interest (`header`) is `nan`.  However, once I start into the for loop it is clear that the `nan` values haven't dropped because I keep getting warnings like:

RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice

which is a result of my array `neighbors` having all `nan` values.

My Question:  In the line where I use `df_copy.dropna(inplace=True, subset=[header], axis=0)` does it seem like I am not actually getting a permanent drop of those rows?

```
n_samples = 10
tolerance = 1.5
dataframe = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
def removeOutliers(dataframe, header):
    dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    df_copy = dataframe.copy()
    #Why doesn't the below actually drop the NaNs?
    df_copy.dropna(inplace=True, subset=[header], axis=0)
    for ii in range(len(df_copy['Lng'])):
        a = df_copy.iloc[ii]['Lng'] -  df_copy.iloc[:]['Lng']
        b = df_copy.iloc[ii]['Lat'] -  df_copy.iloc[:]['Lat']
        c = np.array((a**2 + b**2)**0.5   )    
        d = np.zeros((len(df_copy['Lng'])))
        e = np.zeros((len(df_copy['Lng'])))
        d[:] = df_copy.iloc[:]['Well']
        e[:] = df_copy.iloc[:][header]
        idx = np.argpartition(c, n_samples+1)
        max_loc = np.where(e[idx[0:n_samples+1]] == e[ii])
        neighbors = np.delete(e[idx[0:n_samples+1]], max_loc)
        avg = np.nanmean(neighbors)
        std = np.nanstd(neighbors)
        if df_copy.iloc[ii][header] > (avg + tolerance*std) or df_copy.iloc[ii][header] < (avg - tolerance*std):
            df_copy.iloc[ii, df_copy.columns.get_loc(header)] = np.nan
    return df_copy

test_data = removeOutliers(dataframe, 'myColumn')
```

Comment: Questions on SO are required to be Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and this is none of those. Please a) reduce your code to the absolute minimum that illustrates the issue, preferably a couple of lines. Also, b) you haven't defined `subset=[header]` and c) you need to post your data (we don't have 'my_file.csv') so none of us can execute your code. If you can reduce this to e.g. a 4x4 dataframe and one line of `dropna()` command that would be good.

Comment: *"Does it seem like I am not actually getting a permanent drop of those rows?"* You're doing `df_copy.dropna(..., axis=0)` so `subset=...` will drop *columns* not rows. See [the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html). You still haven't shown us `header` but if it's an array of row-indices that could be your issue.

Comment: The problem comes from what you do in the `if` statement. I think the `dropna` works fine, but if your condition is met, then you change the value of the column `header` by a `nan`, so actually you put back `nan` in your column and some loops after you can end up with a selection of the column containing only `nan`. right?